# Case/PSU grounding, static causing reboot

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, electric-shock

I built a machine for work recently that is displaying two distinct characteristics.

1. Yesterday, I was able to shuffle my feet on our carpet, touch the front of the case, causing a static arc, and the machine rebooted.
2. I've watched the machine seemingly spontaneously reboot. I was suspicious of the [power supply](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817256097) and the [motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128720) since I've never made extended use of products from either manufacturer before. Also, I only code on this box, so it's certainly not getting too hot.

Anyway, I am distinctly lacking any fundamental electrical basics, so I'm not really sure what to do to solve the spark-arc-reboot problem, at least. Though, if anyone else has had issues with that hardware, I'd like to know.

Comment: I've had terrific recent experience with Silverstone PSUs, and not so recently, with Gigabyte motherboards.

Comment: It sounds simple.  You use a different PSU since having a spark-arc by simply touching the case shouldn't happen.

Comment: Since the PSU is painted, you would have to make an effort to ensure that the PC case makes good electrical contact with ground.  If you have a multimeter, then check the resistance between the case and the ground prong.  You should also post a link for the PC case.

Comment: @Ramhound Why shouldn't touching the case cause a spark? If the case has a nice, strong ground with little resistance, it's quite possible to get an arc to the chassis. The current should simply go to ground through the PSU, though. ESD wrist straps have a large resistor that cause any static on the body to be *slowly* drained away, avoiding the arc (and the possible damage). That ESD discharge does produce a very noisy transmission of RF energy, though. This noise can be picked up by the reset line and cause this behavior.

Comment: @Steve - Because its not normal if the power to the PSU is grounded.

Comment: It absolutely is. The charge is carried by the human, not the computer chassis. When the human comes close enough to the chassis, and the static charge on the person is great enough, it will suddenly discharge and cause the arc. It is *the presence of the ground* that permits the arc. It doesn't prevent it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge

Comment: This is why the recommendation is to touch the chassis before handling the ESD sensitive PCBAs - to discharge through the chassis and not an IC, FET, or other sensitive component.

Comment: I hope you didn't screw the motherboard directly to the case and used the distance screws.

Answer (score 1):

A reboot upon static discharge should not happen if the system is properly grounded.

Your power cord should have a three-prong plug, you should not be using a "cheater" plug to adapt it to a two-prong outlet, and the ground connection on the outlet should go to earth ground.

You can buy a $10 tester at Home Depot or Lowe's to test the outlet.

Also, do not use insulating washers with your motherboard mounting screws. They're supposed to ground the mobo to the chassis at all of the mount points. And do use as many as the mobo has mounting holes.

A PC case that has superfluous metal pieces, not electrically connected to the grounded part of the case, will be a problem here. All metal pieces (even painted ones) should be connected to the main case.

Comment: I think you hit it with the last point. The front bezel is (I believe) brushed aluminum that is just screwed into the plastic holding the front USB ports which, in turn, clips into the steel frame of the case. To the other points, I'm using a 3 pronged plug that is going into a UPS. The UPS is plugged into a power bar with a 3 pronged plug as well, but I'll check the whole thing for grounds to the wall when I can. However, if that front bezel is aluminum, will that still be a problem if it's not grounded?

Comment: Yes, if that's what you're touching to make the static discharge.

Comment: @musasabi For the aluminum bezel, if there's a place on it's rear that's exposed from the inside of the case, use a small sheet metal screw to run a small gauge wire (~22ga, strip insulation 1/4" on either end) to either a free screw hole on the internal of the case, or use another small sheet metal screw to screw into an unused section on the internal of the case.  If the aluminum bezel has no exposed area internally for a screw, use a piece of aluminum tape to stick the stripped section of wire to the backside of the aluminum bezel